# call custom JS function inside jquery/ajax that is defined in an external .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

only function excute once, then make then whole part of jquery doesn't work.
I tried to search but i didn't find right answer.
CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Plugs/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Plugs/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Plugs/pop-up.js"></script> <!-- FILE THAT CONTAINS function popup(divNama) { /*instruction*/ } -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //document.write('');
    $("#feeStructure").validate({   
        submitHandler: function(form) { 
              popup('popUpDiv'); // custom fn that fire once and make jquery/ajax stop working
            $.post('michangoProc.php', $("#feeStructure").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#msgErr').html(data);
        }); 
        }
    }); 
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Please have a friend or colleague help you describe the problem clearly in English. As it is, I'm afraid your question is far too unclear to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order that the JavaScript files are loaded.

If you want a function that exists in a file to run in an inline script it must be loaded **before** your inline script. Your code should look like the below. See that the `Plugs/pop-up.js` file import now occurs before your inline script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Plugs/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Plugs/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Plugs/pop-up.js"></script> <!-- FILE THAT CONTAINS function popup(divNama) { /*instruction*/ } -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // $.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function(){ //$.fn.popup=function(){  } ;
        //document.write('');
        $("#feeStructure").validate({   
            submitHandler: function(form) { 
                popup('popUpDiv');
                $.post('michangoProc.php', $("#feeStructure").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#msgErr').html(data);
                }); 
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i tried that but the problem is still there that           popup('popUpDiv'); function fire once, then the whole js/jquery block stop working  until i do refresh page

Comment: @FadhilMakunga I can't help anymore. I don't know what `pop-up.js` does and I don't know what the `validate` method is